# Debian packaging and localization of control files

Tags: debian, packaging, debian-based, software-packaging

Is there a way to provide localized versions of the Debian packaging control files (changelog, control and copyright for example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is laid down in the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/), chapters 4 and 5. I don't see any provision for localisation. I suspect this is because `control` and `changelog` are heavily machine-parsed; allowing the field names to change risks vastly overcomplicating the mechanisms which deal with them. It is a bad idea to localise `copyright` because that is supposed to be a verbatim copy of the upstream package's copyright declaration: also, being a legal document, translating it is risky.

Besides, most users never see these files. Why do you want to localise them?

Comment: My guess: French law requiring every piece of documentation translated to French.

Comment: Nope, but that could be it:) I'm building a package that only makes sense for frenchies (http://github.com/nicoulaj/freeplayerd), and it looks a little bit odd having some parts in english for the end users. Not that big of a deal.

Comment: Ah, I see. For your own package, there's nothing to stop the contents of the changelog, copyright statement or the control file's name and description being in French (or perhaps slightly dual-language so that non-francophones can have an idea what it is they've come across). I see you're distributing via a PPA; if you don't plan to submit the package to the main archives you don't need to adhere tightly to the policy manual.

Comment: I prefer sticking to the Debian policy, my compatriots will have to read the changelog in english ;)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the type of text you want to translate. I suggest to take a look at the Developer's Reference ([8.1. How translations are handled within Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/l10n.html#l10n-handling)).

As far as I know there is no support for `changelog.Debian` translations and the translations of package descriptions are maintained independently of the packages. So far, tha `copyright` files have been plain text files, so it should be possible to include translations in the same file.